# Access denied in Iterating objects in s3 object in Ruby AWS sdk

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3

I'm having trouble trying to list buckets in S3. The permissions are set by my client, and my Ruby script cannot "see" all the objects in a bucket. I want to evaluate each object to see if I can descend into it, but the objects.each iterator is throwing an access denied before I can try and interrogate the acl on the object.

```
`return_or_raise': Access Denied (AWS::S3::Errors::AccessDenied)
```

on the iterator, meaning I never get at it to see if I can read it or not. There is, from what I can see, no documentation on this, and I don't think I should ask my client to make the objects listable so that my iterator can see them. How can I handle this exception and continue to iterate the collection, ignoring the apparently fatal error thrown by the s3 client. Using a begin/rescue is no use..

```
 def order_exists?
   bucket_content = S3Helper.list_bucket_content(@s3,"important_bucket")
     p bucket_content #ok
     bucket_content.objects.each do | s3_object |

       # NEVER dumps, as I don't have access to one of "important_buckets" 
       p s3_object child
     end
```

Oddly, through the console, I can list all buckets, so I would have though the same IAM user could list them in the SDK

Any help very much appreciated...

Mike

Comment: Are you sure that the access/secret key that you are using in ruby code belongs to the same IAM user who can list all the objects from Console?. If you can view/list it from console, then you must be able to view/list it from APIs.

Comment: Hi Thanks, yes - I'm sure. I think the problem lies in the fact that in the gui you can see the bucket, but don't descend into it until you try (when you get the access denied error), but calling "objects" on the bucket in the API tries to descend into it.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Hi no, I gave up with it and changed tack. I'm no Ruby expert but it seemed to be quite problematic. I've done the same thing in NodeJS API with no issues, so I'm assuming a good Ruby Dev would know how to stop  Ruby throwing the error..